# angular multiple ng-content containers doesn't respect template

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular8

We are trying to create a toolbar component that receives its menu items from another component. We want menu items on the left (main nav) and on the right (language + user buttons).

We provide three ng-content sections for this, with a spacer between the first (main nav) and the other two.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<mat-toolbar-row>
  <ng-content select="[fps-navbar-items]"></ng-content>

  <span class="spacer"></span>

  <ng-content select="[fps-navbar-auth]"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="[fps-navbar-language]"></ng-content>
</mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

The problem is that when rendering the page, the spacer has disappeared. 
So all menu items appear on the left.
It's like angular doesn't support static content between the ng-content sections. We tried to added spans/divs around the ng-content elements, but it doesn't help.

The result:
[image: unwanted result (the spacer disappeared!)]

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I rebuilded your case and it works as expected and the spacer is getting rendered just fine. Im running angular 8.2.2 and material 8.1.3. Could you provide more code about how you passing the ng-content to the toolbar?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I don't have access to the code this weekend, I can provide it next week. Our use case is very similar to the example Kenneth posted below. I don't understand why we get a different behavior. To be continued Monday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ng-content>` does not “produce” content, it simply projects existing content. So they should not substitute any code between themselves. See more information in this helpful article (https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b)

You can also check the working example here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avemjm-qzybci?file=app/toolbar-multirow-example.html) which is almost exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kenneth. Our code is very similar to your stackblitz but we get a different result. I don't have access to the code this weekend though, so I can't really test or check anything now. To be continued Monday...

Comment: Okay, my bad. I had fumbled up by passing in the placeholder contents.